# How to disable specific closure DiagnosticType, rather than whole DiagnosticGroup?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I'm trying to use Closure as a sort of linter on steriods in my code. I want all warning on, except for [this particular DiagnosticType](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/a4cb49131c9db49227f188f9ee25d418f82e3bd3/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/TypeCheck.java#L107) (`POSSIBLE_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY`), which causes a ton of noise on my externs. Is there any way to disable that particular diagnostic, without disabling the whole `missingProperties` group?

Answer (score 0):

No - not by default. You would need to make a custom build of the compiler.